# How to add/override method to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, helper, redmine-plugins

I want to override the helper method with my plugin. I tried to create a new helper module with method that should override like this:

```
myplugin/app/helpers/issues_helper.rb

module IssuesHelper
  def render_custom_fields_rows(issus)
    'it works!'.html_safe
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work. Core method still used in appropriate view.

**Hack solution:**

```
issues_helper_patch.rb

module IssuesHelperPatch
  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods

    receiver.class_eval do
      def render_custom_fields_rows(issue)
        "It works".html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end

init.rb

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require 'issues_helper_patch'
  IssuesHelper.send     :include, IssuesHelperPatch
end
```

This is the hack because in normal way methods should be in `InstanceMethods` module of `IssuesHelperPatch` module.

Comment: `return` is implicit if your value is on the last line. Including it does tend to suggest it's there for a reason and can lead to confusion.

Comment: Are you sure this is the method being executed? When you say "doesn't work" you're not specific.

Comment: @tadman I just removed a lot of code to make example smaller so your suggestion doesn't matter. Thanks.

Comment: This method should be executed in issues/show view and it's result should be on page. So I tend to believe that this method being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is IMHO **good** solution for this problem:

```
issues_helper_patch.rb
module IssuesHelperPatch
  module InstanceMethods
    def render_custom_fields_rows_with_message(issue)
      "It works".html_safe
    end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods

    receiver.class_eval do
      alias_method_chain :render_custom_fields_rows, :message
    end
  end
end

init.rb

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require 'issues_helper_patch'
  IssuesHelper.send     :include, IssuesHelperPatch
end
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. You should use metaprogramming which is ideal for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
IssuesHelper.class_eval do
  def render_custom_fields_rows(issus)
    'it works!'.html_safe
  end
end
```